# Is there a standard function in C++, that takes an argument and returns the same?

Tags: c++, function

I want the following function to be used for some binding purpose.

```
template <class T>
T fun(T arg) { return arg; }
```

Is there a standard C++ function available to do this. Or do I have to write my own?

Comment: Could you please provide some context to where and when you would want to use something like that? There may be other solutions?

Comment: What kind of "binding purpose"? I'm not sure if I'm missing something, but I don't see any reason why you would do that.

Comment: Huh, `#define IDENTITY(x) (x)` - just kidding.

Comment: And if `T` is some complex type, copying it like this might be inefficient.

Comment: Such identity functions may be useful, for example, when you need to provide some transformation as a function pointer. In those cases, usually the default transformation is an identity and so you need a pointer to a function which behaves just like that. The user may then override the default behavior with his own function.

Answer (score 3):

I might write it like this:

```
template <typename T>
auto identity(T && x) -> decltype(std::forward<T>(x))
{
    return std::forward<T>(x);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

No there isn't, but you're pretty much done.

I'd call it `id` rather than `fun`, though, since it's the identity function.

Comment: When I see a function called `id(x)` I would expect it to generate/extract an ID number from x. Maybe call it `do_nothing(x)`?

Answer (score 0):

In simple way you could -as said above- use #define fn(x) (x). but when you pass complex data structure to your 'fn' things will get really ugly, let-away its hard to trace back the errors with the misleading compiler messages.

But if your binding issue is some threading synchronization issue. then the answer will be  in how to use the threading API/library for such thing. for Ocaml for example its like something >>= res where we bind till we find the result of something represented with res. let me know if it's the case the name of the library you are using?

have fun.